# Dojo cometD - Configure not working

Tags: javascript, dojo, push, configure, cometd

I'm new to CometD (Dojo) and trying to make a simple script. The first confirm gets shown but the second is not. I also get no error-message even when I use loglevel: 'debug'. All the files needed are includes using googleapis.

```
require(['dojox/cometd', 'dojo/domReady!'], function(cometd)
{
    confirm("test 1");  

    cometd.configure({
        url: http://localhost:8084/Push/,
        logLevel: 'debug'
    });

    confirm("test 2");

    cometd.handshake();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CometD files shipped by Dojo are completely empty. Frankly I don't know why, will ask to the Dojo guys (see also https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18063).

What you have to do is to follow the CometD instructions here: http://docs.cometd.org/reference/primer.html.

Once you have the proper CometD files in place, your script will work fine.